# Send SMS via VoipBuster using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sms

I am total beginner, but I am trying to make a macro in VBA to send an SMS using VoipBuster platform when a condition is completed.

Is it possible? Is it easier to use the application installed on PC or web page (https://www.voipbuster.com/sms).

Please help!

Comment: Just check with voipbuster.com where in they give you API to call send sms function from excel.

Comment: Hi Santosh, on the web I see that it is possible but I cannot figure out what exactly to look for...

Answer (score 1):

For send sms from voipbuster you can send it by php vars...


`"https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=$USER&password=$PASS&from=$FROM&to=\"$TO\"&text=$SMS_TEXT"`

So you need to access iexplore from vba like this , create you vars use, pass, text etcc and concat everythins like the URL before ..

to call iexplore from VBA you will find a lot of ways with google , here you got an example

```
Private Sub IE_Autiomation()
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim IE As Object 
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.Navigate "https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=$USER&password=$PASS&from=$FROM&to=\"$TO\"&text=$SMS_TEXT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. You can also test by putting the value in URL variable to your browser.

```
Sub SendSms()

    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim sendTo As String
    Dim msg As String

    username = "test" 'enter username here
    password = "test" 'enter password here
    sendTo = "9999999999"
    msg = "Hello"

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username=" & username & "&password=" & password & "&to=" & sendTo & "&text=" & msg

    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", URL, False
    xml.send
End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh I get this Error: Automation error (Error 440) or System Error: 02146697202, anything wrong? and highlights "xml.send"

Comment: https://www.voipbuster.com/myaccount/sendsms.php?username="test"&password="test"&to="9999999999"&text="Hello"   Kindly replace the details with correct and put direcly in your browser and let me know the response.

Comment: I cannot access this as I am at work and have limitted access, I will let you know later, thank you! Can I ask you if in the line "URL=" do I need to replace the password= and other with actual ones that I use to login and text message?

Comment: Yes you need to replace with acutal ones as the website needs authentication. Ofcourse the mobile no has to be correct along with a message.

Comment: I just thought that if we declare them via DIM above, than they are considered already in URL line...but I will try this, thank you!